# WPF bound to ObservableCollection - Control Rows?

Tags: .net, wpf

I want to display a grid with two columns - name and progress. Name should be a string, progress is a percentage value between 0.00 and 1.00. I'd like the percentage to be displayed as a progress bar or something alike.

I have a DataGrid in my Window, created a simple class with a double and a file name. My main Code holds this:

```
public ObservableCollection<DownloadFile> files = new ObservableCollection<DownloadFile>();
```

I then set the `ItemsSource` to this collection, the auto generate columns is set to true. It works fine up to now, including updating.

Now the double Value inside the class is ment for a value between 0 and 1, a percentage. Since there is no progress bar, I decided I could alter the background Color of the corresponding row, like this:

```
row.cell.Style.Background = new LinearGradientBrush(
    Brushes.Green.Color,
    Brushes.White.Color,
    new Point(percentage, 0.5),
    new Point(percentage + 0.1, 0.5));
```

Is there any way to somehow .. control what the Grid is displaying? Right now, I'm either overwhelmed by the differences or the DataGrid is a huge step back from the old DataGridView, which wasn't all to great either. But this seems to be completely bound to some real Data I cannot alter manually all too easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know number of columns and their types, it's better to create them explicitly and set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false`. The first one will be a `DataGridTextColumn`, for the second one we'll create a custom template:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding FilesDownloading}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="File" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="{Binding Progress}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

It seems like you'll be updating the progress as the file downloads, so you'll need your `DownloadFile` class to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Also, this makes it easy to send a message when download completes:

```
public class DownloadFileInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private double _progress;
    public double Progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set
        {
            _progress = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Progress");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, it works! Thank you very much, looks like I'll really have to look closer into that whole XAML Structure!